# Language string failed to load: tls - SMTP error

Tags: ssl, smtp, phpmailer

I have Integrated PHPMailer to send emails via SMTP with outlook email .Getting this "Language string failed to load: tls" SMTP error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It tells me that you are using a very old version of PHPMailer that's no longer supported. [Get the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Comment: I have included class.phpmailer.php and class.smtp.php files in my code, I Can see PHPMailer version 5.2.28 in class.phpmailer.php file. Where can i download these files with recent version

Comment: Exactly: those files have not existed in PHPMailer for several years now. I already gave you the link to the new version, so go there and read the docs on upgrading from older PHPMailer versions, which is covered in the readme, and in further depth in the upgrading guide linked from that same page.

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion Synchro, I have installed the recent version 6.5 and updated the code, Now I am getting "could not connect to SMTP host" error,

Comment: So now read the troubleshooting guide on the PHPMailer project site, and search for that error message on Stack Overflow. It's most likely because your hosting provider is blocking outbound SMTP, or that you're running into problems with gmail credentials.

Comment: Iam getting "Could not Authenticate error" even though i have given correct credentials in the code and it is for outlook. Do i need to change any settings in my outlook other than in my code, If so Please suggest

Comment: Enable debug output and read the SMTP transcript, then look up what you find in the troubleshooting guide.